# How to input a empty star by LaTeX

Tags: symbols

Of course I know the `\star` can make a filled star symbol. But how to input a empty star? It is like:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are plenty of empty stars, both in text and math mode.

In the following some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mnsymbol}

\begin{document}
From \texttt{mnsymbol}: $\largestar \medstar \smallstar$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some others:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
From \texttt{fdsymbol}: $\largewhitestar \medwhitestar \smallwhitestar \smwhitestar$ 

From \texttt{bbding}: \FiveStarOpen

From \texttt{fontawesome}: \faStarO

\end{document}
```

[image]

And some others again:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}
From \texttt{stix}; $\bigwhitestar \medwhitestar \smwhitestar$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Directly from: [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

All the previous examples can be compiled with `pdflatex`.

Comment: It's always good to use as many symbol fonts as possible in one document ;)

Comment: @TeXnician I hope the OP will choose only one of them :):):)

Answer (score 4):

With `pdflatex` and `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\STAR{\raisebox{-.7em}{\tikz{\node[draw,star,star point height=.7em,minimum size=1em]{};} }}

Put a star \STAR here ..

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With [`pifont`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pifont?lang=en):

```
\usepackage{pifont}
\ding{73}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Width `xelatex` or `lualatex` and

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
....

$\medblackstar \medwhitestar$
```

[image]